# Using SignalR (or any WebSockets framework) server from microcontroller client programmed in C

Tags: websocket, asp.net-core, embedded, signalr, rpc

I am still thinking what is the most proper WebSockets framework to learn, which gives me all what I want.

I am C#.Net Core programmer (it is the language I want to use to write my server with). I wanted to start learning SignalR, but I didn't start yet because I am still confused about the ability of using my SignalR server from a Microcontroller client.

Is it some how possible to use transfer data between SignalR C#.Net Core server and an ARM Cortex M4 microcontroller programmed in C (without any operating system on it)?

In case that is not possible with SignalR, which WebSockets framework may be useful for my case (C# Server <-> C client)?

Any further ideas and suggesions about that? I am still very new to WebSockets and I don't understand exactly if it is possible to use SignalR (or any WebSockets framework) server from a client uses another framework (or maybe pure websockets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SignalR for ASP.NET Core you can actually use bare websocket to connect to the server. I showed a demo where I have 3 different clients connecting to the SignalR server. The interesting part is that one of the clients was a NodeMCU based board running lua. You can find all the details in my [post](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/01/15/signalr-core-part-23-asp-net-sockets/) including code and instructions on setting things up.

Comment: I guess you are the same guy from Microsoft I watched his video about SignalR. In the being time I find SignalR difficult to learn, because I want to use it with ASP.Net Core, and there is no good documentation till now. I didn't spend much time because that guy (which I guess you are) said that everything might change because it is still in alpha phase. Actually I intend to use any available C library with my ARM Cortex M4 MC, because I have no idea about Lua. what I understand from your blog is I am going to use pure WebSockets some how, will reading Lua code help me to achieve that in C?

Comment: Nope. I am not this guy :). I presented this at the MVP Summit in Redmond while Damian presented at the NDC in London. Things are still changing rapidly but it's getting more stable and most of the changes are above the ASP.NET Sockets layer (i.e. in hubs etc.). I mentioned lua to show that new SignalR can work with any conforming WebSocket client without having to have a dedicated SignalR client. As such if you find a WebSocket library in C it should just work.